# Databinding Error: old values should be followed by new values. Parameter 2 must be the same type as parameter 3

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

I am using data binding for my custom fields. I have set a custom data binding adapter for this.

My Binding Adapter looks like this:

```
@BindingAdapter({"created_by,created_at"})
public static void setDetailCreated(TextView textView, String createdBy, long createdAt) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(createdAt);

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a, dd MMM yyyy");

    String format = textView.getContext().getString(R.string.details_created, createdBy,
            dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));

    textView.setText(format);
}
```

And in my layout file I have:

```
 ...
 <data>

    <import type="java.util.Map" />

    <import type="com.example.beans.Friend" />

    <variable
        name="user"
        type="com.example.beans.User" />

    <variable
        name="friends"
        type="Map&lt;String, Friend&gt;" />

 </data>

 ....
 ....

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:created_by="@{friends[user.createdBy].name}"
        app:created_at="@{user.createdAt}" />
```

But while running I am getting the below error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: failure, see logs for details.
>     BindingAdapter setDetailCreated(android.widget.TextView,java.lang.String,long): old values should be followed by new values. Parameter 2 must be the same type as parameter 3.

I don't understand what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Error is within your `BindingAdapter`, it should be

```
@BindingAdapter({"created_by","created_at"})
public static void setDetailCreated(TextView textView, String createdBy, long createdAt){

}
```

all the values should be comma seperated and in double quotes.

Comment: Oh... You saved me! Silly mistake!  Good catch !

Answer (score 4):

In Kotlin it looks like this for me:

```
@BindingAdapter("created_by", "created_at")
@JvmStatic fun setDetailCreated(textView: TextView, createdBy: String, createdAt: Long){
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: hope you are not used to write `pubic static void` in Kotlin :P

Comment: can omit `*arrayOf`